# Finding amount of repetitions to achieve an error in Jacobi's method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a question about a problem that am trying to solve. I am given matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0\\-1 & 2 & -1\\0&-1&2\end{pmatrix},
$$ and matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\3\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It said that after doing $2$ repetitions of the Jacobi method using as starting vector $x_0=[0,0,0]$ to calculate the amount of repetitions we need to achieve an error lower than $10^{-4}$

My problem is that i try to use the formula $||x-x_k||<||c||^k/(1-||c||)||x_1-x_0||$ but I found that norm of $c$ is $1$.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: By doing the calculation in python it comes out that i need 29 repetitions

Comment: It depends on $c$. My $c$ is $I-A/2$ and its norm is $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel yes I figured out I calculated a different norm and solved the problem by finding the |C-λi| and took the max λ as a value for my norm which gave me one more repetition than what i calculated in python so i guess its right

Comment: Indeed, it depends on the norm you use. $1$- and $\infty$-norms would lead nowhere, but the $2$-norm does the job. It should lead to the prediction of $31$ steps or something like that.